# How can I connect to my company's git hub portal using java?

Tags: java, github, github-api, jcabi

I have tried using jcabi-github following is my code

```
Github github = new RtGithub("<Oauth token>");
Iterable<Repo> repo =  github.repos().iterate("");
for (Repo repo2 : repo) {
    System.out.println(repo2);
}
```

But this is giving error

```
{"message":"Bad credentials","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}>
at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
```

I am trying to connect to my company's git hub account which is https://github.corp.xyz.com/

Any help?

Comment: The message is saying bad credentials and the code is showing no credentials. The javadocs for jcabi-github don't appear to have any information about authentication either. Unless there is a good reason i'd contact the developers and ask how you would authenticate.

Comment: This is the part of code which is used for authentication. Github github = new RtGithub("<Oauth token>")      Read on their website/blog that I could either pass username/password aur OAuth Token

Comment: Try with a username/password,

Comment: Have tried with username/password as well

Comment: If you are doing repeated requests, you may have hit the throttling limit, which results in "Bad credentials" messages even if everything is fine. Wait a while and it will go away; or use a different account.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this by using https://github.com/kohsuke/github-api

Here is the code for future reference:

```
GitHub github = GitHub.connectToEnterprise(
                        "https://github.corp.<abc>.com/api/v3",
                        "<Oauth token>");

GHContentSearchBuilder search = github.searchContent();
GHContentSearchBuilder s = search.q(<searchkeyword>);
```